# How can I modify this to work with any regex with capture groups?

Tags: c#, regex

Because I used named groups in the following code it only works with a specific regex. How can I modify it to take any regex and output all capture groups as csv?

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
try
{
    rg = new Regex(@arguments.Regex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@arguments.FilePath))
//audit.log
{
    var loginMatch = rg.Match(line);
    if(!loginMatch.Groups["username"].Value.Equals(""))
    {
    sb.Append($"{loginMatch.Groups["username"].Value},{loginMatch.Groups["time"].Value},");
    }
}
Console.Out.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Please never write `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }` in your code. It is unnecessary as the debugger will let you know what errors you have. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate `loginMatch.Groups` using a loop or LINQ, for example

```
for(int i = 1; i < loginMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
  sb.Append($"{g[i].Value},");
sb.Length--; //trim off last comma
sb.AppendLine();
```

Or

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", loginMatch.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g => g.Value)));
```

Given that `Group.ToString()` also returns the value, I suspect these could be simplified some too, e.g...

```
for(int i = 1; i < loginMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
  sb.Append(g[i]).Append(",");
```

plus the trim/newline, or

```
string.Join(",", loginMatch.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1));
```

plus the `sb` bit

---

If you've named some groups but not others, and you don't know what the names are, but you only want to put the named ones in the CSV, turn on `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` and remove the Skip/set the loop to start from 0. The Skip/1 is there to avoid including the default capture (the input) in the file, but if you have only explicit captures there won't be a default group so your captures will start from 0

Totally agree with Enigmativity's comment; use a CSV writer library, or make this code more involved with regards to escaping commas in the data etc.. I didn't add that complexity to the post because I'm specifically addressing the query of how to enumerate capturing groups

Comment: You should probably escape double-quotes and commas.